# Kit Kat SMS changes affecting Jelly Bean 4.3?

Tags: android, sms, abortbroadcast

I have some apps that use SMS broadcast receivers to exchange messages with a high priority and then use abortBroadcast so that the system does not get the message.  I have a LG 2.33 phone and a Galaxy S3 phone running jelly bean 4.3 that I use for testing.  The apps work fine on these phones and they have been working fine for users of my apps.

I realize the KitKat 4.4 broke all of this and I'm in the middle of converting to GoogleCloudMessaging.

However, I see today that the abortBroadcast is not working on the Jelly Bean 4.3 phone any longer!!  The user is getting my internal messages as SMS messages.  That phone hasn't had an operating system change since January 2014.  How is it possible that the SMS behavior has changed on the 4.3 phone??

thanks,
Gary

Comment: How do you know abortBroadcast is not working as intended? abortBroadcast was never guaranteed to always work anyway. There was always a chance that another SMS client would increase the priority of their Broadcast Receiver and so that it would get the broadcast before it got aborted, and so then you would have to delete the SMS manually yourself (assuming it was stored in the usual content provider, which was also not always guaranteed either).

Comment: in my testing using <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647" > I was getting the SMS before any app I could find and abortBroadcast always worked in all my tests.  My thousands of users had no complaints either.  Now it ALWAYS fails on Jelly Bean 4.3 on my Galaxy s3 running 4.3.  What changed on that phone?

Comment: Google Hangout, the standard SMS App from Samsung, WhatsApp, MSN Messenger (now Skype), etc. Any of those apps could have changed their priority setting in one of their updates.

Comment: Yes, Hangouts is causing the behavior.

Comment: I facing this issue recently too, any idea to overcome this issue?

Comment: Ricky.  Yes, it's no longer viable to use SMS to communicate between phones.  I switched to Google Cloud Messaging - not a trivial change.